# Are there any HTTP Request Headers which ISPs (Virgin Media etc) recognise in order to prevent their DNS Hijacking?

Tags: http, security, dns, http-headers, httprequest

In the UK, Virgin Media will return a "200 OK" for any domain that doesn't exist as they hijack the DNS and return their crappy search page ([example](http://advancedsearch2.virginmedia.com/main?InterceptSource=0&ClientLocation=uk&ParticipantID=jqlc435patgs4w79dx7g33u8otdryt35&FailureMode=1&SearchQuery=&FailedURI=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.redd32it.com%2Fapi%2Flogin%2F&AddInType=4&Version=2.1.8-1.90base&Referer=&Implementation=0)).

I am wondering if ISPs honour any type of request header to guarantee my application won't fail in the event I try to access Reddit.com's API and their domain is down temporarily. Because at the moment, if reddit.com was to be down and my application sent a GET or POST, Virgin Media would intervene and serve a 200 OK because they are idiots.

I know you can manually opt out but that only works on my end, I can't ask every user of my application to follow their ISPs instructions to opt out of this mess of a "feature".

I've tried setting things like `Accept` to only `application/json`, yet Virgin Media will still return their crappy search page with `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`.

My only solution so far seems to be detecting the content type *(as I'm always expecting JSON)* or scraping the HTML returned for any mention of "virgin media". Although it would be nice if I could set a certain header to guarantee Virgin and other ISPs won't intervene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain not existing is not the same as the host not responding. If `reddit.com` was down, their DNS would still resolve to their server, it would just be their server that is not replying to packets.

You can test this by trying the following two links:

- http://www.example.com:81 - this would be very similar to the host
  being down.
- http://www.example.invalid - this would be exactly the same as the host not resolving to an IP.

Not having a Virgin Media connection myself I cannot test this, but it would be usual for an ISP to proxy connections and replace missing HTTP responses with their own (although not entirely unheard of).

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. But then this is still a problem if their DNS was to go down, I'd still receive a `200 OK`.

Comment: @xLite: Very unlikely due to the nature of DNS infrastructure and caching. To answer your question there is no header and there is nowhere for the header to be sent - by the time the HTTP connection has been established, Virgin Media have already resolved the invalid host to their search server.

Comment: Damn, well thanks for the response. Much appreciated!